# Integer solutions to an ellipsoid surface

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory

Given the equation $$x^2+2y^2+5z^2+xz =n$$ where $n$ is any positive integer, what is the smallest odd integer for which no integer solution $(x,y,z)$ exists (i.e. $x,y,z$ are integers)?

I know that for $n=10$ that no integer solution exists, but locating an odd number $n$ that has no integer solution has proven to be quite difficult.

Computer approaches seem to indicate that the number of integer solutions for odd $n$ grows as $n \to \infty$. It seems to me that in fact there are no integer solutions for any positive odd $n$. Do we see any proofs as to impossibilty (or can we find an odd $n$ that has no integer solution?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an open conjecture that the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+5z^2+xz$ represents all odd positive integers, see **Conjecture 1** [*here*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.0979v2.pdf).
The same conjecture holds for the quadratic forms
$$
Q(x,y,z)=x^2 +3y^2 +6z^2 +xy+2yz, 
$$
and
$$
Q(x,y,z)=x^2 +3y^2 +7z^2 +xy+xz.
$$
There is at present no general algorithm for determining the integers represented by a positive-definite ternary quadratic form $Q$.

Comment: One "should" expect the conjecture to be true, since it is a known consequence of GRH.